# REST API return dummy data not visible from the web

Tags: rest-api

I'm playing with the REST API using PHP. I have managed to connect successfully and to run some SOQL queries.

I want to fetch all the emails of every Contact entity in my instance so I run the following query:

```
SELECT Email FROM Contact LIMIT 1000
```

And here is the result:

rose@edge.com,  sean@edge.com, jrogers@burlington.com, ... and so on.

The problem is that this is a brand new salesforce account with ZERO contact... I guessing this is some dummy data returned by the API because i'm using a developer account? If this is the case where can I turn off this behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct - when you create a new Developer Edition it is populated with sample data. There's no way to turn this off, but you can easily delete the sample data.

In Apex:

```
// NEVER DO THIS IN PRODUCTION!!!
// These are the main Standard Objects - add more if you need to
delete [SELECT Id FROM Case]; // Need to delete cases before contacts - referential integrity
delete [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity];
delete [SELECT Id FROM Lead];
delete [SELECT Id FROM Contact];
delete [SELECT Id FROM Account];
delete [SELECT Id FROM Campaign];
delete [SELECT Id FROM Solution];
delete [SELECT Id FROM Product2];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with the API (and it sounds like you are), then @metadaddy's answer is probably the best.

If you don't want to use the API, you can mass delete records in a developer edition by using the [mass delete records tool](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_massdelete.htm).

Also, if you're using a trial organization, you can [mass delete all of the trial data](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=deleting_trial_data.htm).

[image]